# WAMP starts up (green) but doesnt fully restart (orange)

Tags: windows, apache-http-server, process, wamp, httpd

When I open the WAMP manager it goes to green and everything works.
Then (also without doing anything else) when I click the icon and choose `restart all services` it goes to orange and stays orange. Also when I try again.

**There are no errors in the apache log, PHP log or mysql log.**

When I watch the process in Task Manager I see that the child process is stopped if I choose `stop all processes` but the parent process is not.

If I kill the parent process from Task Manager and then retry wamp becomes green again.

So basically it looks like apache is not properly stopped? What can cause this?

It is a fresh install, though I did already have another WAMP installation onder C:/wamp. The new one I installed under C:/wamp2. I just turned on some apache modules and installed APCU. But like I said, everything starts up perfect and no errors in the logs.

Comment: If you remove APCU does this still happen.

Comment: Also check the Windows Event Log for messages from Apache

Comment: For future reference : [The proper way to install a new release of WAMPServer](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,123606)

Comment: Are you sure you have all the correct version of the MSVC Runtime libraries, [see the WAMPServer TroubleShooting Tips](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,134915) Specifically POINT20

Comment: Does that upvote signify that the solution was to install the MSVC runtimes?

Comment: that wasnt me. just checked the Windows Event Log, nothing there except MySQL saying it stopped normally. Then when I manually end the httpd service ofcourse some warnings about that.

Comment: following the tips on the page you gave I see with `services.msc` that the wampapache service is still on 'stopping'.

Comment: I would guess you have more than one apache and/or MySQL on your system.

Comment: Do you have a service called `MYSQL` or `Apache` running, use `services.msc` to look for this WAMPServers versions are called `wampapache` and `wampmysqld` or if you are 64bit WAMPServer `wampapache64` and `wampmysqld64`

Comment: I see both `wampapache` and `wampapach64`. The previous wamp I had installed was 64 bit, the new one 32bit. But only the 32bit services (`wampapache` and `wampmysqld`) are running, untill I try to restart them with WAMP, then `wampapache` stays on `stopping`

Comment: I also see the service `Apache2.4` which points to the same path as `wampapache` (the newly installed apache). There is no status (its not running) and startup type: Automatic

Comment: What about the `mysqld` ones as well?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35260/discussion-between-riggsfolly-and-flion).

Comment: yes I see `wampmysql` and `wampmysql64`, though no other ones, and the 32bit version correctly stops and starts, unlike the apache service

Answer (score -1):

Probably when you restart wamp services. Apache service is not started may be because of port conflict. When restarting check either one of these [Skype/teamviewer] is not running. You can check Windows Event Viewer logs also to find the exact problem.

Comment: nope no skype or teamviewer running. I checked the ports and the previous httpd parent process is still taking hold of port 80. I kill it and all is fine.

Comment: If it was a port conflict it would not start the first time